# Eclipse Aptana HTML PHP Highlighting seems incorrect for href

Tags: php, html, eclipse, aptana

This is my first question on this forum, so I apologize in advance if it seems stupid.

I did install Aptana studio 3 plugin for Eclipse to learn PHP/HTML/CSS..etc. I just have a highlighting issue.

I wanted to post an image here but alas I don't have the requisite 10 point reputation.

Is there any way to color the text I type in this forum to illustrate my issue? I checked advanced help so it seems not...

Thanks Chris

Comment: Did you select theme from the toolbar?

Comment: Post the image *elsewhere* then, like imgur.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies, here is the image on imgur    _[Image](http://i.imgur.com/AqyhOiR.jpg)_